# Self Installing Zip Archives ( run app after extracting )

Tags: linux, archive, installation

I'm creating an self extracting archive using unzipsfx.exe and with command:

```
cat unzipsfx.exe archive.zip > Installer.exe
```

I need to execute an exe from archive.zip after Installer.exe extracts content.

Need to do that from PHP installed on Linux.

I can use exec function from PHP but need to know what to execute.

Answer (score -1):

Self-extracting archives are proper executable files, and if you're creating an `.exe` file, it's a Windows executable, and you can't execute it under Linux.

(If there is a way to execute it anyway [virtualization, Wine, etc.] then you need to execute the executable file itself.)

Comment: I will execute under windows, I need after extracting to execute a file from archive ( setup.exe ).